# How do I change this filter expression into a paramaterized query?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

Good morning all,
how would I turn this filter expression into a paramaterized query but still display in the gridview? Right now, if I search for %^&%* it crashes.

C#:

```
public static bool IsDate(Object obj)
        {
            string strDate = obj.ToString();
            try
            {
                DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
                if (dt != DateTime.MinValue && dt != DateTime.MaxValue)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

 protected void BtnWinnersSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string searchText = txtWinnersSearch.Text.Replace("'", "''").Trim();
            bool isDate = IsDate(searchText);

            GridViewWinners.Visible = true;

            if (isDate == true)
            {
                SqlDataSource4.FilterExpression = "dob" + " ='" + Convert.ToDateTime(searchText).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                SqlDataSource4.FilterExpression = "nickname like '%" + searchText + "%' or username like '%" + searchText +
                    "%' or clubnumber like '%" + searchText + "%' or firstname like '%" +
                    searchText + "%' or lastname like '%" + searchText +
                    "%' or email like '%" + searchText + "%'";
            }
        }
```

ASP:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlWinners" DefaultButton="BtnWinnersSearch" runat="server" Visible="False">
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><b>MANAGE WINNERS</b> - 
            <asp:Button ID="BtnWinnerAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" 
                    onclick="BtnWinnerAdd_Click" /> | 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtWinnersSearch" runat="server" MaxLength="220"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:Button ID="BtnWinnersSearch"
                    runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="BtnWinnersSearch_Click"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridViewWinners" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PlayerID"
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" 
                EmptyDataText="There are no winners to display." CellPadding="4"
                AllowSorting="True" 
                onsorting="GridViewWinners_Sorting" 
                ForeColor="#333333" 
                Visible="False"
                onselectedindexchanged="GridViewWinners_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                    FooterStyle-Wrap="False" HeaderStyle-Wrap="False" PagerStyle-Wrap="False" 
                    RowStyle-Wrap="False" SelectedRowStyle-Wrap="False" Font-Overline="False" >
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                        VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PlayerID" HeaderText="PlayerID" InsertVisible="False" 
                        ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PlayerID" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nickname" HeaderText="Nickname" 
                        SortExpression="Nickname" ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" 
                        SortExpression="LastName" ItemStyle-Wrap="False">
                    <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" 
                        SortExpression="FirstName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" 
                        SortExpression="UserName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ClubNumber" HeaderText="Account Number" 
                        SortExpression="ClubNumber" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" 
                        SortExpression="Email" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="D.O.B." 
                        DataFormatString="{0:d}" SortExpression="DOB" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                        HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" 
                        HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </asp:Panel>
             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="****" 
                ProviderName="***" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT [PlayerID], [Nickname], [UserName], [ClubNumber], [FirstName], [Email], [LastName], [DOB] FROM [Players] order by lastname ASC">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

[image]

Error:

> Error in Like operator: the string pattern '%@#%$%' is invalid.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.EvaluateException: Error in Like
>   operator: the string pattern '%@#%$%' is invalid.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [EvaluateException: Error in Like operator: the string pattern
>   '%@#%$%' is invalid.]    System.Data.LikeNode.AnalyzePattern(String
>   pat) +1251846    System.Data.LikeNode.Eval(DataRow row, DataRowVersion
>   version) +345    System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op,
>   ExpressionNode left, ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion
>   version, Int32[] recordNos) +13013
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version) +29
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left,
>   ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[]
>   recordNos) +13013    System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version) +29
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left,
>   ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[]
>   recordNos) +13013    System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version) +29
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left,
>   ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[]
>   recordNos) +13013    System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version) +29
>   System.Data.BinaryNode.EvalBinaryOp(Int32 op, ExpressionNode left,
>   ExpressionNode right, DataRow row, DataRowVersion version, Int32[]
>   recordNos) +13013    System.Data.BinaryNode.Eval(DataRow row,
>   DataRowVersion version) +29
>   System.Data.DataExpression.Invoke(DataRow row, DataRowVersion version)
>   +151    System.Data.Index.AcceptRecord(Int32 record, IFilter filter) +103    System.Data.Index.InitRecords(IFilter filter) +303    System.Data.Index..ctor(DataTable table, Int32[] ndexDesc,
>   IndexField[] indexFields, Comparison`1 comparison, DataViewRowState
>   recordStates, IFilter rowFilter) +491
>   System.Data.DataTable.GetIndex(IndexField[] indexDesc,
>   DataViewRowState recordStates, IFilter rowFilter) +228
>   System.Data.DataView.UpdateIndex(Boolean force, Boolean fireEvent)
>   +165    System.Data.DataView.UpdateIndex(Boolean force) +12    System.Data.DataView.SetIndex2(String newSort, DataViewRowState
>   newRowStates, IFilter newRowFilter, Boolean fireEvent) +113
>   System.Data.DataView.SetIndex(String newSort, DataViewRowState
>   newRowStates, IFilter newRowFilter) +17
>   System.Data.DataView.set_RowFilter(String value) +160
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.FilteredDataSetHelper.CreateFilteredDataView(DataTable
>   table, String sortExpression, String filterExpression, IDictionary
>   filterParameters) +396
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +2012
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   +75    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2496

Sincerely,
Christopher Witalis Peterson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried parameterizing the searchText like '%' + @SearchText+ '%' instead?

Comment: Good morning Ispep Aloc, No I have not. How would you recommend me doing so exactly? Thanks for your help thus far. Sincerely, Christopher Witalis Peterson

Comment: SelectCommand="SELECT [PlayerID], [Nickname], [UserName], [ClubNumber], [FirstName], [Email], [LastName], [DOB] FROM [Players] where Nickname like '%'+@Nickname+'%' order by lastname ASC">
                <SelectParameters>
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtWinnersSearch" Name="Nickname" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"/>
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

Answer (score 0):

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT [PlayerID], [Nickname], [UserName], [ClubNumber], [FirstName], [Email], [LastName], [DOB] FROM [Players] where Nickname like '%'+@Nickname+'%' order by lastname ASC">
                <SelectParameters>
                     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtWinnersSearch" Name="Nickname" PropertyName="Text" Type="String"/>
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```